# Как изменить цвет пункта ListView при нажатии на него и сохранять его цвет при проматывании списка?

Tags: меню, android, listview, список

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить цвет пункта ListView при нажатии на него и сохранять его цвет при проматывании списка?

Вот код MainActivity:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp2;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView.*;
import android.graphics.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final String[] sites = new String[] { "iPhone", "Барсик", "Мурзик", "Мурка", "Васька", "Томасина", "Кристина", "Пушок", "Дымка", "Кузя", "Китти", "Масяня", "Симба" }; // используем адаптер данных 
        final Integer[] categories = new Integer[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}; // используем адаптер данных

        ListView categories_listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.categories); // определяем массив типа String 
        ListView sites_listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.sites);
        ArrayAdapter<String> sites_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.sites, R.id.label, sites); 
        categories_adapter categoriesAdapter = new categories_adapter(this, categories);
        categories_listview.setAdapter(categoriesAdapter);
        sites_listview.setAdapter(sites_adapter);

    categories_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    }});

        }

        }
```

Вот код адаптера:

```
    package com.mycompany.myapp2;

import android.content.Context; 
import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView; 
import android.widget.TextView;

public class categories_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Context context; 
private final Integer[] values;
    private final Integer[] image_adress = new Integer[]{R.drawable.ic_stub, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_stub, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_stub, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_stub, R.drawable.ic_stub};

public categories_adapter(Context context, Integer[] values) { 
super(context, R.layout.categories, values);
this.context = context; 
this.values = values; }

@Override 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categories, parent, false); 
ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon); 
for (int i = 0; i<values.length; i++){
if (values[position] == i) {
icon.setImageResource(image_adress[i]); 
}

    }

return view; 
}

}
```

Comment: И еще: как сбрасывать цвет пункта, нажатого прежде?

Comment: Может покопаться в сторону селекторов?

Comment: Можно пример?